# Docker ARG command not finding file

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to pass an .obj file on my computer to a docker file then ADD it to the image, but I am getting a file not found error. The file I am trying to access is even in the same folder as the dockerfile, but that may not always be the case.

After running this command...

sh maya-pipeline.sh **/Users/kromah/Documents/Developer/Github/Unity/unity-pipeline-maya/house_data/0004d52d1aeeb8ae6de39d6bd993e992/main.obj**

### maya-pipeline.sh

```
echo $1
docker build --build-arg house=$1 -t dock .
```

The echo command outputs the file location

### Dockerfile

```
FROM mottosso/mayabase-centos

MAINTAINER marcus@abstractfactory.io


ARG house=/house_data/0004d52d1aeeb8ae6de39d6bd993e992/main.obj
ADD $house /root/pipeline
```

### Error Message

```
lstat Users/kromah/Documents/Developer/Github/Unity/unity-pipeline-maya/house_data/0004d52d1aeeb8ae6de39d6bd993e992/main.obj: no such file or directory
```

Comment: the lstat errors does not show the '/' as if you entered the path without specifying the root directory. - Edit: nvm I know what is wrong, I make an answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker does not allow you to ADD files **out** of where the Dockerfile sits (outside the current Dockerfile's directory or its subdirectories).

Docker's dev team say this is for "security reasons" : by not allowing this, it avoids malicious Dockerfiles to try to import your precious /etc/passwd or shadow files, or others ;-)

So basically, any path not starting with the root directory of your Dockerfile **cannot** be added within the container, neither with ADD nor COPY.

Note that symlinks wont work better.

Answer (score 0):

I workaround is cp the file to the directory the Dockerfike is in.